# How to know the position of your website in Google?

Tags: google-search

How to know the position of your website in Google search.

Comment: Sounds more like a question for [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At Google webmaster tools**

Setup you site there and wait a few days.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Answer (score 0):

There are several options: The first is to actually do the search manually...

As far as web apps, check out [Rankiac](http://rankiac.com), it is a great service and easy to use!

Answer (score 0):

Webmaster tools is the proper tool provided by Google itself. Other than that, there are third party softwares to know that. Traffic travis is one of them, where you can enter keyword list you want to check the ranking and run the test.